# WordPress, removing comments block programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to remove Word Press comment block from specified 'n' posts. These posts are generated dynamically and don't want comment block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using [wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) to generate the posts? If so, set the option "comment_status" to "closed" when inserting.

To change the status on an existing post, use [wp_update_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post); you'll only need to send in the ID and the comment_status options to close (or open) comments.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that, without even going into the code, would be to uncheck "display comments" at the bottom of the post you create inside the wordpress admin area.

Alternatively, you could disable comments altogether by going into the "Settings » Discussion" part in your admin area and deselecting "Allow people to post comments on new articles".

Comment: thanks from your help, but I am adding posts dynamically using PHP code, so it would be a tedious job to go to admin panel and remove/uncheck "display comments". I need to do it programmatically

Answer (score 0):

The comment block of items is in listing files the articles of the mainpage or of each of the categories you have created.
Check out the archive /index.php in your Wordpress and see the HTML comment block.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but this should work in your index.php/single.php file..

```
$posts_to_hide_comments = array(1, 3, 8, 9, 10, 13, 17, 24);

if (! in_array($post->ID, $posts_to_hide_comments, true)) {

    comments_template();

}
```